# Settings - Initialize Application Scope Setting Property

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

Simple question, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere to this.

How do I store the `MachineName` in the `Settings` of an application.

I've tried just saving `System.Environment.MachineName`, and didn't work. Is there a symbol that I need to use to let it know that's something it has to get?

Note that I don't want the `MachineName` being set by the `User`, but by the `Application`.

Comment: How did it not work? `System.Environment.MachineName` is what I use everywhere.

Comment: Probably you forget to save settings after assigning value to setting property.

Comment: @RezaAhaei, I typed it in, in the settings window. So...I set it before the application even runs.

Comment: When you type it in Settings designer, it means you store "System.Environment.MachineName" string in the setting. You should assign the value to the property at runtime and save it at runtime.

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default.MachineName = System.Environment.MachineName;` then `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

Comment: @RezaAghaei But what if I want to set the scope to the `Application` and not the `User`,  how can I get the application to fetch the name?

Comment: I can share a solution to initialize an Application scope setting but I'm interested to know what's your imagination of Application settings which makes you to try to save `MachineName` as application settings? What's the problem with being user settings? What's the problem with using  `System.Environment.MachineName` directly?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Learning experience, and because I don't want the user touching that specific setting.

Comment: OK, I posted an answer just for learning purpose.

Comment: Maybe the answer doesn't satisfy your requirements but it's the answer to your question. It initializes an *Application* scope property using `System.Environment.MachineName`. Do you have any problem applying the solution?